# Run jquery animated gif on form next button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that has multiple pages, on one of the page I’m using a web service to return a value (triggered on the next button) that is then displayed on the next page. 
The value return takes over 20 second and want to use an animated gif to let the user know something is happening, I am using a jquery page animation that is normally fired using

```
$(window).load(function() {
        // Animate loader off screen
        $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");;
});
```

I have tried $(window).unload(function() nut this seems to fire straight away andnever leaves the animation.

Ideally I would like to fire the animation on the next button:

Next
And run while the web service is getting the information but npo sure hope this is done.

I have tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.button').on('click', getAn);
});

function getAn () {
            $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");;
});
```

But this doesn’t fire. I also don't have acess to modify the html. 
Is it possible to use an animated gif like this or is it really only for page loading?

Comment: As a matter of personal preference, I'd suggest CSS loading spinners rather than gifs. Apply a `visible` class to it when you click next (before sending the request) then remove it when the request returns. I'd need to see more of the code to really help any more than that.

Comment: $('.button').on('click', function(){
$(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
}); P.S. Does your button really have class 'button'?

Comment: What does the console say? any error? what is your HTML? more info may be required.  Iit's probably not the source of the problem, but in your second example the function getAn has a spare parenthesis at the end, before the semicolon. That `)` needs to be removed.